# Somebody explain to me why we never write directly to state in Redux?

Tags: object, redux, immutability

I was really confused with Object.assign() used to in redux.

I don't understand why does the below code working..

```js
import { createStore } from "redux"

const userReducer = function (state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_USER_NAME":
      state.name = action.payload
      break;
    case "CHANGE_USER_AGE":
      state.age = action.payload
      break;
    default:
  }
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(userReducer)

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

store.dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_USER_NAME", payload: "paul" })
store.dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_USER_AGE", payload: 74 }) // It returned { name: "paul", age: 74 }
store.dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_USER_NAME", payload: "john" }) // It returned { name: "john", age: 74 } changed name to "john" but age is same. This point. is not immutable object?
```

I just write directly to state's value, but the result is the value I expected...

`user.name` is changed but `user.age` is not changed.

It looks like an immutable object to me. Am I wrong ?

Somebody explain to me why we never write directly to state ?
Sorry about my dummy question. I was trying reason but I don't know why..

Comment: Because that's not how React is designed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why we want to always return a new object, you have to understand pure functions and side effects in functional programming.

Pure functions take arguments as their input data and *return* data or functions as their output. This allows us to not mutate the input, but instead produce new data off of the input.

In this way the original state will remain unchanged, and instead will be replaced by an entirely new state object, keeping your function pure, not producing side effects.

Comment: Thank you, Simeon!! 

I learn pure functions in your comment.

I just added 2 line, my code is broken up.


`let copiedVariable = store.getState();

copiedVariable.name = "ringo"


store.getState() // { name: "ringo", age: 30 }`

so I wish this question and answer could help people like me!

Answer (score 0):

```
const userReducer = function (state={
  name : "",
  age : ""
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_USER_NAME":
      state ={
        ...state ,
        name : action.payload
      }
      break;
    case "CHANGE_USER_AGE":
      state ={
        ...state ,
        age : action.payload
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
  return state;
}
```

This is the right way to store data in the state so that it doesn't overwrite the previous state .