# React/Redux: cannot detect state has changed

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm using redux and my app cannot detect a state change.

This is my redux data model:

```
allPosts
  -post{key,body}
    -comments
      -comment{key,body}
      -comment{key,body}
      -comment{key,body}
```

**ViewComponent + container**

(post is passed by prev screen. it is from redux store.)

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class CommentList extends React.Component {
  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.props.dispatch(fetchComments(key)); <== to call redux action to fetch comments
  }

  renderItem = .... //skip the code

  render() {
    const { post, authorProfile } = this.props;
    console.log("props post is ... ", post);
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.commentList}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        data={post.comments}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.header(authorProfile)}
        ListEmptyComponent={<Text>No Comments</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}

CommentList.propType = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToPropsFactory(initialState, ownProps) {
  const { createdBy } = ownProps.post;
  return function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      authorProfile: state.user.authorProfiles.find((profile) => (profile.uid === createdBy)),
    };
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToPropsFactory)(CommentList);
```

**Action**

```
export const fetchComments = (postkey) => (dispatch) =>
    new Promise(() => {
        // fetching data ...
        // and then receive comments
        comments.forEach((comment) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_COMMENT',
                key: postkey,
                comment
            })
        })
    })
```

**Reducer**

```
case 'ADD_COMMENT':
    return Object.assign([], state.map((data) => {
    if (data.key === action.key) {
      const oldComments = data.comments ? data.comments : [];
      if (oldComments.map(m => m.key).includes(action.comment.key)) {
        return data;
      }
      oldComments.push({
        key: action.comment.key,
        body: action.comment.body,
        createdBy: action.comment.createdBy,
        createdAt: action.comment.createdAt,
      });
      data.comments = Object.assign([], oldComments);
    }
    return Object.assign([], data);
  }));
```

I'm using Object.assign because [somebody-explain-to-me-why-we-never-write-directly-to-state-in-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083153/somebody-explain-to-me-why-we-never-write-directly-to-state-in-redux)

I was thinking this is not wrong, but it doesn't work properly.

When I open `CommentList` at the first time, the comment is not be displayed. But, when back and reopen, it's displayed.

So, I thought it's because redux cannot detect an object changed in the state.

I changed the code like this:

**ViewComponent + container**

```
function mapStateToPropsFactory(initialState, ownProps) {
  const { key, createdBy } = ownProps.post; // add key
  return function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      authorProfile: state.user.authorProfiles.find((profile) => (profile.uid === createdBy)),
        anyanyanyany: post: state.posts.allPost.find((post) => (post.key === key)), // add this statement
    };
  };
}
```

after I do this, it works properly. Please tell me how to code reducer in this case?

Comment: Fetching data from componentWillMount is an anti-pattern, that can lead to unexpected behaviour. You can read more about cWM functioning here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7671

Comment: @Dez thank you for responding.I didn't know that.I'll check it. thank you

Comment: It's quite possible the state change is deep and redux doesn't observe it because it only does shallow comparisons: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585#issuecomment-133028621

Comment: @MattyK14 Thank you for responding.I know that redux deos shallow comparisons.so I return new assigned object as state in reducer.but it doesn't work.but if container pass any posts object ( regardless whether we use it or not in viewcomponent) as props,it become working properly.